# Find the number of ways in which the number 30 can be partitioned into three unequal parts.(Please use multinomial theorem)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

OfLet $a,b,c$ be the parts such that $a<b<c$
Now, let $a−b=x,     b−c=y,$   implies     $x,y>0$
$⇒a+b+c=30\\
⇒(b+x)+b+c=30\\
⇒x+2(c+y)+c=30\\
⇒x+2y+3c=30$      ,

$c≤27$
Sum =30,Co-eff =$1,2,3$
$(x^1+x^2+.......)×(x^2+x^4+.......)×(x^3+x^6+.......+x^{27})$
Co-efficient of $x^{30}$ in the above product will give us the required answer.=$x×x^2×x^3×(1−x)^{−1}×(1−x^2)^{−1}×(1−x^3)^{−1}\\
 =x^6\times (1−x)^{−1}\times(1−x^2)^{−1}\times(1−x^3)^{−1}$

Please help me to understand the last ,how to find the coefficient of p^24 in those 3 brackes

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). [PSQs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33854/what-is-a-psq) (problem statement questions - where you just paste the problem and ask "what is the answer") do not belong on Math.SE. Consider adding context to the question such as what you've tried so far or what you're stuck on. Also, please use $\LaTeX$ to format your questions so they are readable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty much on the right track. The last part is pretty tedious, so it might be better that you just use Wolfram Alpha or possibly some other program. I think you defined your variables a little wrong. For example, if $a<b$, then $a-b<0$. However, you defined $x=a-b$, but you are saying that $x>0$. It looks like you're fine if you instead force $c<b<a$.

As you found before, we want to find the coefficient of $x^{24}$ in
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$$
Our goal will be to convert this into something of the form
$$\frac{P(x)}{(1-x^a)^b}$$
We can then use the fact that
$$\frac{1}{(1-x^a)^b}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+b-1}{b-1}x^{na}$$
to find the coefficient of $x^{24}$ in the resulting expansion. The most tedious part of this process is determining $P(x)$. We will start with some manipulations of
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$$
Note that $1-x, 1-x^2,$ and $1-x^3$ are all factors of $1-x^6$ (I think this would be called the LCM). Using this, we get
$$=\frac{(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x^3)}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1-x^2)(1+x^2+x^4)(1-x^3)(1+x^3)}$$
$$=\frac{(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x^3)}{(1-x^6)^3}$$
$$=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x^3)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}x^{6n}$$
Well that was simple. However, the hard part is yet to come. We need to find the coefficient of $x^{24}$ in that expansion. Denote the product of the leftmost $3$ polynomials (the ones not in the summation) as $P(x)$. We will be finding the coefficient $x^{24}$ in the expansion of
$$P(x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}x^{6n}$$
Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}x^{6n}$ only has terms of powers $0\mod 6$, we only care about the terms with power $0\mod 6$ in the expansion of $P(x)$. Although this doesn't help us too much, it does reduce some of the calculations. Expanding $P(x)$ while only caring about the **final** terms whose powers are $0\mod 6$ gives
$$P(x)$$
$$=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x^3)$$
$$=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^7)$$
$$\sim 1+x^6+x^6+x^6+x^6+x^{12}$$
$$=1+4x^6+x^{12}$$
So we only need to find the coefficient of $x^{24}$ in
$$(1+4x^6+x^{12})\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}x^{6n}$$
$$\binom{4+2}{2}+4\cdot \binom{3+2}{2}+\binom{2+2}{2}$$
$$=15+40+6$$
$$=61$$
Indeed this matches what [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20series%20of%201%2F%28%281-x%29%281-x%5E2%29%281-x%5E3%29%29) gives (just click more terms on the taylor series expansion until you get to $x^{24}$)

Answer (score 1):

Since, I'm learning a bit of residue theory, I want to try this solution out as well. We want to find the coefficient of $x^{-1}$ in the expansion of
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{25}(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{25}(1-x)^3(1+x)(1+x+x^2)}$$
This is just the residue at $0$. $f(x)$ also has residues at $1,-1,\omega,\omega^2,\infty$. Where $\omega$ is the third root of unity. We have
$$f(x)=\frac{-1}{x^{25}(x-1)^3(x-(-1))(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)}$$
The residues at $-1,\omega,\omega^2$ are respectively
$$-\frac{1}{2^3}$$
$$-\frac{1}{9}$$
$$-\frac{1}{9}$$
The residue at $\infty$ is $0$. The residue at $1$ is
$$-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{1}{x^{25}(1+x)(1+x+x^2)}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{d}{dx}-\frac{25(1+x)(1+x+x^2)+x(1+x+x^2)+x(1+x)(1+2x)}{x^{26}(1+x)^2(1+x+x^2)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{d}{dx}\frac{25}{x^{26}(1+x)(1+x+x^2)}+\frac{1}{x^{25}(1+x)^2(1+x+x^2)}+\frac{1+2x}{x^{25}(1+x)(1+x+x^2)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 1} -\frac{25(26(1+x)(1+x+x^2)+x(1+x+x^2)+x(1+x)(1+2x))}{x^{27}(1+x)^2(1+x+x^2)^2}-\frac{25(1+x)(1+x+x^2)+2x(1+x+x^2)+x(1+x)(1+2x)}{x^{26}(1+x)^3(1+x+x^2)^2}+\frac{2x(1+x)(1+x+x^2)-(1+2x)(25(1+x)(1+x+x^2)+x(1+x+x^2)+2x(1+x)(1+2x))}{x^{26}(1+x)^2(1+x+x^2)^3}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{25(156+3+6)}{36}-\frac{150+6+6}{72}+\frac{12-3(150+3+12)}{108}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1375}{12}-\frac{9}{4}-\frac{161}{36}\right)$$
$$=-\frac{4367}{72}$$
Since the sum of all the residues must be $0$, we have that the residue at $0$ is
$$\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{4367}{72}$$
$$=\boxed{61}$$

Yeah, this was not the best method in retrospect. Computing the second derivative was very tedious and error prone (had to check with Wolfram several times), but the method does work. In my opinion, I think the other method I posted of just manipulating the generating function would be a lot more effective in these types of problems.

Comment: So i found a easier method to this problem instead of  finding  coefficient of x^24 ,just find the number of non-negative integer solution of 3x+2y+z=24,that comes from the series expansion of all the three  terms.and its a hell lot easier to find the numbers of non-negative integer solution.

Comment: @TECHNOHACK could you elaborate? Is this not the same approach as what I did in the first solution?

Comment: Yaa but finding the integer solutions in this is much easy as we can easily club 24 and 3x then just count the number of solutions using multiples of 2

Comment: @TECHNOHACK Yes, that is true for small numbers such as $24$. Both methods I gave readily generalize for larger numbers, which would not be as easy to brute force.

Comment: Yaa ur method is more generalized and can be applied to any number,for smaller numbers integer solution approach is fine.thanks for the help by the way i was searching for the method to find coefficient and u just gave an amazing method.thanks for ur time .