# How can I find the integral of $1/\big(z^{N+1}(1-z^{a_1})(1-z^{a_2})(1-z^{a_3})\big)\,$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, number-theory, contour-integration

I'm solving the problem of finding the number of solutions for $$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3=N,\quad\quad\gcd(a_1,a_2,a_3,N) = 1,$$

and I found out that it is
$$I(N) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R<1}\frac{dz}{z^{N+1}(1-z^{a_1})(1-z^{a_2})(1-z^{a_3})}.$$

How can I calculate it or find its asymptotics ?

P.S. sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: The $a_i$ are any integers or are they positive integers? In general I would try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: They are natural numbers I guess

Comment: Doesn't look easy to compute. This looks like it ought to be related to counting solutions of $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 = N$, which can be done with Euclid's algorithm if you allow negative numbers. But I don't see how to generalise it.

Comment: I don't think there is a general method. I did a similar problem (not the general case) in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4310314/find-the-number-of-ways-in-which-the-number-30-can-be-partitioned-into-three-une/4310339#4310339 . As you can see, both of the methods are rather messy